# Checkout of packages into a catkin workspace

Tags: ros, catkin-make, ros-hydro, wstool, rosinstall

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I try to create a catkin workspace and add some packages from git-repositories to it.
the manual process seems straight forward:

```
mkdir my_ws; cd my_ws; mkdir src; catkin_make
source devel/setup.bash
cd src
git clone <pkg1>; git clone <pkg2>; ...
cd ..
catkin_make
```

I'm a bit confused on which tools to use in order to make this a bit more user friendly. I tried

```
mkdir my_ws; cd my_ws; mkdir src;
rosinstall -c src pkg_1_to_N.rosinstall
catkin_make
```

But rosinstall creates a top-level CMakeLists.txt file different from catkin_make and the subsequent build fails.
If I call catkin_make once before rosinstall, the rosinstall command fails trying to overwrite the CMakeLists.txt file, as the existing one is a link to /opt/ros/hydro/...

It seems like wstool is a replacement for rosws. But I did not yet find an example of how to use it as a replacement for rosinstall.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/111746/checkout-of-packages-into-a-catkin-workspace/) by [roadrunner](https://answers.ros.org/users/9576/roadrunner/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2013-12-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`rosinstall` needs to be called with `--catkin` if you do not want it to generate those files.

Another option is to use `wstool`, which is a refactoring of `rosws` for catkin workspaces.

http://wiki.ros.org/wstool

You can do a lot of things with `wstool`, like having it fetch your `.rosinstall` file's contents:

```
$ mkdir -p ~/my_ws
$ cd ~/my_ws
$ wstool init src /path/to/my.rosinstall -j8
```

This will fetch all the entries in the `my.rosinstall` file into the `src` folder and it will fetch up to 8 (`-j8`) in parallel.

Then you can just run `catkin_make`:

```
$ catkin_make
```

You can also use `wstool` to modify your "workspace", using it's other verbs:

```
$ wstool set -t src my_serial --git https://github.com/wjwwood/serial.git -v 1.1.6
$ wstool update -t src
```

This will add the git repo, at the specified version, to the workspace with a target folder in the workspace of `my_serial`. The update command will actually fetch the code. Notice that you must always specify the target workspace after the verb with `-t src`.

Hope that helps.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2013-12-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [roadrunner](https://answers.ros.org/users/9576/roadrunner/) on 2013-12-18**:
`wstools init src ...` does the job. Great!

Is ``wstools`recommended to use instead of`rosinstall`&`rosws```?
It is kind of confusing to have those parallel tool chains that do almost, but not quite the same...

Is `rosinstall --catkin` any different from `rosinstall -c`?
From `rosinstall -h` it seems that `-c` is just the short version of `--catkin`.
I also get the same error, as described above.

Thanks!

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-12-18**:
`rosinstall` just operates on `.rosinstall` files, but used to do some extra stuff for `rosbuild`, which is why the `--catkin` flag is needed. `rosws` and `wstool` are for workspace management (so modifying and updating a folder with rosinstall behind the scenes). `rosws` is for rosbuild and `wstool` is for catkin. I would recommend using `wstool` for everything catkin and `rosinstall` or `rosws` for rosbuild.

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-12-18**:
Also, `wstool` is "for catkin", but really is meant to be completely ROS and catkin agnostic, just lets you maintain a workspace of many repositories of many types (git, hg, svn, tar).